# dropdown list does not fill in Jquery, Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I  wanna to fill a drodown-list through jQuery, Ajax,
at first dropdown list is visible =false
when user click a button it will be appeared and at the same time have to be filled with data,

every thing is good, but data does not fill the dropdown list
I utilize this link for making this code:
[link](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1145/mvc-dropdownlistfor-fill-on-selection-change-of-another-dropdown)

**I put an alert in the each in javascript, and so I found that it pass the data,
as it iterated 10 times(according my data in db) but why just it does not show the data?????**
this is my dropdown list

```
<input type="button" onclick="edit(@item.Barcode);" value="خرید" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">

<div class="pull-left" style="display:none" id="pnlSize">
  <label class="control-label">سایز:</label>
  <div class="product-quantity" id="drpSize">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Size, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty
    <SelectListItem>(), "ID", "Size"), "انتخاب همه", new { @class = "form-control" })
  </div>

</div>
```

this is my Javascript:

```js
< script >

  function edit(Barcode) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("selectedItemChanged")',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        barcode: Barcode
      },
      success: function(result) {
        // when the AJAX succeeds refresh the dropdown list with
        // the JSON values returned from the controller action
        var selectedDeviceModel = $('#Size');
        selectedDeviceModel.empty();
        $.each(result, function(index, item) {
          selectedDeviceModel.append(
            $('<option/>', {
              value: item.value,
              text: item.text
            })
          );
        });
      }
    });
    $('#pnlSize').show('fast');
    var val = $('#drpSize :selected').text();
    if (val != 'انتخاب همه' && val != null) {
      location.href = '@Url.Action("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart")?Barcode=' + Barcode + '&size=' + $('#drpSize :selected').text();;
      //window.location.href = url.replace('Barcode', Barcode);
    }
  }
< /script>
```

this is my controller code:

```
public JsonResult selectedItemChanged(string barcode)
{
    AdidasWebsiteEntities context = new AdidasWebsiteEntities();
    var itemsList = context.tblSiteSizes.Where(item => item.Barcode.Substring(0, item.Barcode.Length - 3) == barcode.Substring(0, barcode.Length - 3)).ToList();
    return Json(new[]
    {
        new {
            value=itemsList[0].ID,
            text=itemsList[0].Size
           } 

    });
}
```

hope one kindly take some time on this, I become tired of testing and surfing the net

Comment: Your ajax response is an array or an string having option tags in it ?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: @MayankPandey its an array, , u can see that in the selecteditemchanged, thx

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am almost beginner, so your speech does not make sense for me, How I can get it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it may happen for someone else,
the problem with the above code was that the name of dropdown list (Size)
and the name of its items I mean (size) was the same,

once I changed the name of Dropdown list it got fixed